# UIContainerView element under the view where he is contained

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I've a little problem with a `UIContainerView`. Each element from my `containerView` are under my ViewController generated by my `UIPageController`

This image will be more explicit :

[image]

So here, my blue button will be under the `UIImageView` (viewController at the bot) and i need it over it. I don't understand why, if someone have an I idea.

**Result** :

[image]

How i create my PageVieWController :

```
 fileprivate func createPageViewController() {
    let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageController") as! UIPageViewController
    pageController.dataSource = self

    if contentImages.count > 0 {
        let firstController = getItemController(0)!
        let startingViewControllers = [firstController]
        pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    pageViewController = pageController
    addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
    pageViewController!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

And how i instantiate my pageItem :

```
fileprivate func getItemController(_ itemIndex: Int) -> ABTutorialPageItemViewController? {
    if itemIndex < contentImages.count {
        let pageItemController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemController") as! ABTutorialPageItemViewController
        pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
        pageItemController.imageName = contentImages[itemIndex]
        return pageItemController
    }
    return nil
}
```

> If you want to manipulate, show directly in action you can use this project :
>   https://github.com/YanisSOTO/Simple-UIPageViewController-Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replacing :

```
self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
```

to :

```
 self.containerView.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
```